# Prevent bootstrap select's dropdown from closing when clicking the dropdown div without event.stopPropagation()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown, bootstrap-select

We have a custom bootstrap select where we have 3 extra buttons alongside the options, when you click any of the buttons, including the action buttons (Select all, Select None, Done/Close) you can keep selecting, considering this is a multiple selector. The problem is that when you click inside the dropdown but miss a button, i.e. click in the gap between buttons, the dropdown closes.
We have tried **event.stopPropagation()** but the main problem with this is that this can lead to messy bugs, and currently the *Done* button doesn't close the dropdown.

```
$('div.dropdown-menu').on('click', function (event) {
var events = $._data(document, 'events') || {};
events = events.click || [];
for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    if (events[i].selector) {

        //Check if the clicked element matches the event selector
        if ($(event.target).is(events[i].selector)) {
            events[i].handler.call(event.target, event);
        }

        // Check if any of the clicked element parents matches the 
        // delegated event selector (Emulating propagation)
        $(event.target).parents(events[i].selector).each(function () {
            events[i].handler.call(this, event);
        });
    }
}
    event.stopPropagation(); //Always stop propagation  
});
```

Any workarounds are welcome, currently we are trying to select the button handling the click button but we can't get to get the jQuery element for that button, and we need it everytime a new bootstrap select is created, we need to have it working when the select is created.